# Как получить угол из матрицы вращения?

Tags: математика, матрицы

К примеру для задания позиции, скейла, вращения и т.д. я использую матрицу (что само собой разумеется), но, иногда, мне также нужно получить эти значения (позицию, скейл, угол) и если с первыми двумя все довольно просто, то не совсем очевидно как получить угол из матрицы.

Comment: Например, для матрицы вращения (3D)  вокруг оси X возьмем значение центрального элемента, а это cos(a), соответственно отсюда получаем угол. Для остальный осей аналогично

Comment: @AlexanderChernin вот только косинус углов 90 и 270 равен 0 - получается, что нельзя определить в какую сторону повернут объект

Comment: в таком случае надо смотреть значение синуса +1 это 90, -1 это 270.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если речь идёт о 2D матрице чистого вращения (не о комбинированной матрице произвольного аффинного преобразования), то угол поворота можно получить как

```
Fi = atan2(-A[0,1], A[0,0])
```

Знак первого элемента зависит от того, используется эта матрица для правого или левого умножения (т.е. координаты представлены столбцом или строкой)

Comment: А если матрица комбинированная?

Comment: Тогда нужно раскладывать на произведение нескольких матриц. В некоторых случаях это нетрудно - выделяется сначала перенос, потом масштаб, потом вращение.  А при наличии сдвига, если не ошибаюсь, нужно проводить мат. процедуру SVD или другого разложения

Comment: может посоветуете статью на эту тему?

Comment: Из старого - [Graphics Gems 3 стр 108](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol1/CMC/Graphics_Gems_3,ed_D.Kirk.pdf) Для 2D [простой пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159314/decompose-2d-transformation-matrix)